# How can I convert an ArrayList<String[]> to a double[] that contains decimal values?

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist, double

I've taken in my inputs using a buffered reader, like so:

```java
private static ArrayList<String[]> dataItem;
private static double[] CONVERT;

public static ArrayList<String[]> readData() throws IOException {
    String file = "numbers.csv";
    ArrayList<String[]> content = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content.add(line.split(","));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { }
    return content;
}
```

I have a `csv` file with values like this:

```
0.2437,0.2235,0.9,0.2599,0.1051,0.1635,0.3563,0.129,0.1015
0.2441,0.3012,0.9,0.1123,0.1079,0.4556,0.4008,0.3068,0.1061
0.2445,0.4806,0.9,0.1113,0.1081,0.354,0.4799,0.3487,0.1034
```

I want to create a double array (`double[]`) so I can run through the file one line at a time in my program. How can I take the lines from the file and create this array from them?

Comment: So you need to get `double[]` or `double[][]` as the result?

Comment: @AlexRudenko i believe double [], i will make this clearer in the question. sorry about that!

Comment: A `double` *cannot* contain decimal values. It uses a binary radix. Do you mean 'fractions'?

Comment: ``Double.parseDouble(String)`` will allow you to convert a String to a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the CSV data are read successfully into `List<String[]>`, the conversion to 2D double array may be implemented like this using Stream API:

```java
static double[][] convert2D(List<String[]> data) {
    return data.stream()
        .map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)
                .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray()) // Stream<double[]>
        .toArray(double[][]::new);
}
```

---

If a simple `double[]` array is needed without keeping the lines, the contents of `data` may be converted using [`Stream::flatMapToDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToDouble-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
static double[] convert1D(List<String[]> data) {
    return data.stream()
        .flatMapToDouble(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)
                .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)) // DoubleStream
        .toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing them in an intermediate `List<String[]>` why not just process them as you read them?

- Use `Files.lines` to read in the lines as a stream.
- split each line on a `,`
- `flatMap` to a single stream
- convert to a double via `Double::parseDouble`
- and store in an array.

```
String file = "numbers.csv";
double[] results1D = null;
try {
    results1D = Files.lines(Path.of(file))
            .flatMap(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(",")))
            .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray();
    
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results1D));
```

prints

```
[0.2437, 0.2235, 0.9, 0.2599, 0.1051, 0.1635, 0.3563, 0.129, 0.1015, 0.2441, 0.3
012, 0.9, 0.1123, 0.1079, 0.4556, 0.4008, 0.3068, 0.1061, 0.2445, 0.4806, 0.9, 0
.1113, 0.1081, 0.354, 0.4799, 0.3487, 0.1034]
```

Or you can store each line in an array and create a `"2D"` array.

- Use `Files.lines` to read in the lines as a stream.
- split each line on a `,`
- stream the array
- convert each line to a double array
- and package all the double arrays into an array of arrays.

```
double[][] results2D = null;
try {
    results2D = Files.lines(Path.of(file))
            .map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split(","))
                    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                    .toArray())
            .toArray(double[][]::new);
    
} catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
}
for(double[] d : results2D) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(d));
}
```

prints

```
[0.2437, 0.2235, 0.9, 0.2599, 0.1051, 0.1635, 0.3563, 0.129, 0.1015]
[0.2441, 0.3012, 0.9, 0.1123, 0.1079, 0.4556, 0.4008, 0.3068, 0.1061]
[0.2445, 0.4806, 0.9, 0.1113, 0.1081, 0.354, 0.4799, 0.3487, 0.1034]
```

Either way is more efficient by not having to iterate thru the input again.

Comment: You may find this useful, if not for this application, then others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single *Stream* for this purpose:

```java
List<String[]> contents = List.of(
"0.2437,0.2235,0.9,0.2599,0.1051,0.1635,0.3563,0.129,0.1015".split(","),
"0.2441,0.3012,0.9,0.1123,0.1079,0.4556,0.4008,0.3068,0.1061".split(","),
"0.2445,0.4806,0.9,0.1113,0.1081,0.354,0.4799,0.3487,0.1034".split(","));
```

```java
// convert a List<String[]> to a double[] using a single stream
double[] doubles = contents
        // Stream<String[]>
        .stream()
        // Stream<String>
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        // DoubleStream
        .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
        // double[]
        .toArray();
```

```java
// output in three lines
IntStream.range(0, doubles.length)
        .forEach(i -> {
            if (i % 9 > 0)
                System.out.print(" ");
            else if (i > 0)
                System.out.println();
            System.out.print(doubles[i]);
        });
```

Output:

```
0.2437 0.2235 0.9 0.2599 0.1051 0.1635 0.3563 0.129 0.1015
0.2441 0.3012 0.9 0.1123 0.1079 0.4556 0.4008 0.3068 0.1061
0.2445 0.4806 0.9 0.1113 0.1081 0.354 0.4799 0.3487 0.1034
```